# Copiar la imagen Captcha a un picturebox C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, windows

estoy haciendo un pequeño programa que sirve solamente para abrir sesión en una página, pero a mi me gustaría ver el código captcha que muestra la misma en un PictureBox de mi programa. ¿Es posible esto?  :huh:

Ya sé como hacer que lo que ingrese en un Textbox de mi aplicación se cargue en el formulario de login de la página directamente usando GetElementById y InvokeMember para hacer los clic en los botones (aclaro por si hace falta)  :P

No estoy diciendo tratar de interpretar lo que dice el captcha (como para hacer robot y eso) solo mostrarlo en un PictureBox

Espero que me orienten un poco en esto y que haya sido claro.

Saludos.

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy amplia, dado que depende de la tecnología de captcha que tenga implementado el sitio, a grandes rasgos la mayoría solo son una imagen, puedes descargarla como cualquier imagen, el problema es que esta se genera y valida  con  las cookies de sesión del usuario, así que también tendrías que capturar estas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depende mucho del sistema que use la pagina para generar el captcha, pero a grandes rasgos puedes hacer lo siguiente.

si tu captcha es una imagen osea el código te marca algo así

```
 <img src="../jcaptcha.jpg" />
```

solo descargarla

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) 
  {
    client.DownloadFile(new Uri('https://dominio/jcaptcha.jpg'), @"c:\temp\captcha.jpg");

   }
```

probablemente cuando la descargues no sera la misma que viste , ya que estas se generan dinamicamente, ahora bien lo importante es que si vas a enviar un `request` con la respuesta es que debes de incluir en ella las mismas `cookies` de sesión que cuando la descargaste, de lo contrario siempre te marcara incorrecto

Comment: muchas gracias por su conocimiento

Comment: Si esta respuesta solucionó tu problema puedes agradecerle al autor marcándola como aceptada en la palomita a la izquierda de la respuesta @RodriguezMartinezAlfredo. Saludos

Comment: gracias no me había tocado responder por a qui gracias por la información